# How to set css style dynamically with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```
<div style="width: 50px !important">
```

I want to set the pixel number dynamically by angularjs. The final width should also be calculated times a base pixel width. How could I achieve this?

```
<div ng-style="{{width: (model.number * 30)px !important}}">
```

This does of course not work, but shows what I'm trying to achieve. I'd like this do be done without having to introduce a controller function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p> Number: <input type="number" ng-model="model.number" /> </p> 

  <p> Times:  <input type="number" ng-model="model.times" /></p>
  <p style="outline:1px solid black; width:{{model.number*model.times}}px;" >Resulding width: {{model.number*model.times}} px</p>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
  $scope.model = {
    number: 50,
    times: 2
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<div ng-style="{width: (model.number * 30) +'px'}">
```

Comment: If you need a couple of css rules simultaneously use commas:
`<div ng-style="{width: (model.number * 30) +'px', height: (model.number * 40) +'px',}">`

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
<div ng-style="{'width': model.number * 30}">
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.